# Microsoft Visual Studio: Windows and Unix project source code compatibility

Tags: c++, windows, unix

I'm going to develop a command line tool for both Windows and Unix OS architectures. However I'm facing a struggle. How can I make the code effectively transferrable between Windows and Unix?

Project is going to be made in C++ language using primarily MS Visual Studio. However I want my tool be cross-platform, so I can use it both in Windows and Unix systems. Since Unix doesn't support Visual Studio, I need to somewhat design the code structure to support both architectures (both being 32bit) and OS-specific headers need to be included for just the only one OS architecture the code is built in.

So I am asking for your help. What is the most effective way to maintain pretty much the same code for both Windows and Unix, with all neccessary headers for that particular OS? So I can create program.exe file in Windows and program.run file in Unix? Some conditions to test current OS architecture (Windows or Unix) and include OS-dependent headers?

What about encoding? Because Windows command line uses MS-DOS encoding (In Central Europe, it's DOS codepage 852), and Unix terminal uses UTF-8 encoding. My tool will be multilingual (with contributors, starting with English and Czech languages from my side).

I need to keep the code structure as small as possible, and of course easily maintainable. The source code shall be available for clone/fork from GitHub repository.

If this is not the kind of question apropriate for Stack Overflow, then just tell and I'll delete it. Just asking for help, nothing else.

Comment: Start using `CMake` to generate your projects. Don't use any OS functionality directly if possible. Use standard c++. If you need some OS functionality see if boost provides what you want. Use git for your code. Don't put any binaries or even generated files (like project files) in the repository only source code.

Comment: Yeah, use `cmake`.  It's supported by VS 2017 now, and will help with header differences without having to make things OS-specific.  When that's unavoidable, put that code into an OS abstraction layer.

Comment: I have VS 2015 Community Edition. Does it support CMake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1) set up your continuous integration system to build the code on Windows and Unix every time from day one. Preferably with multiple compilers on each platform.

Step 2) Use a cross-platform build system like [scons](http://scons.org) or [cmake](https://cmake.org).

Step 3) Don't use *any* platform specific code in your program at all - and when you *have* to, implement multiple versions under various `ifdef` guards. Prefer using cross-platform libraries instead.

Step 4) make sure you have plenty of unit tests (*especially* for the bits where you had to implement something multiple times using platform specific code) and make sure your CI system runs *all* the tests for every commit.

Step 5) Make sure all text is UTF-8 encoded from day one - conversion to other encodings *can* happen at the display layer, but keep everything UTF-8 clean internally.

Step 6) Do extensive manual testing on all supported platforms.

And make sure to tweak every compilers warning setting waaay up and make warnings errors (and fix all such errors). What's a warning with one compiler on one platform can often be silently miscompiled code with a different compiler on another platform.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your tips. Installed CMake 3.10.1 in my Windows machine and going to install it also in my Linux virtual machine...

Comment: @Polda18 - Linux VM?  I'd check out the `WSL` feature in Windows 10 if that's available to you.  It's...*extremely* convenient for development compared to a VM.  A VM is fine and will work, of course.

Comment: @zzxyz - Do you mean Ubuntu Shell feature? Mine install got corrupted and shuts down immediately after booting up. Doesn't even want to uninstall for fix...

Comment: I would add: 7) Follow the C++ standard and avoid Undefined Behaviour constructs. An UB can compile just fine in one compiler/OS but go haywire in another. MSVC has pretty decent support for C++14, but C++17 is still in progress. At the moment Microsoft claims ~75% support of it.

Comment: @Polda18 yeah. That whole install sits in one Windows directory, so you can just clobber it. Worth a 2nd look. I’m happy with it and not the only one.

Comment: Well, I do not own a CI server, and CI server host is pretty much expensive for me. I'll stay with manual tests. It's pretty small utility, more like terminal tool rather than command line utility. All it's supposed to do is just control a wikibot.

Comment: @Polda18 nothing is stopping you from running CI (like a Jenkins or BuildBot server) on your local workstation, with the build-slaves being Virtual Machines that are spun up on demand. A CI system is (IMHO) a must have, even if everything is running locally.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well, I've been searching through Google for pretty reasonable time and found nothing I can work with :( How can I set up personal CI localhost server?

Answer (score 0):

First, the windows console can use utf-16 but not utf-8. Second, if you stick to the standard c++ library, possibly extended with boost (which will have to be installed both on windows and any *nix system you are going to build on) you really should not have any problems so long as you are talking about strictly accepting command line arguments performing work and printing results.

If you are talking about terminal control (that is, printing on the screen somewhere other than the next character cell, in particular going backward) this is going to be quite a bit more difficult.

I would, however, suggest that you use a cmake based project, Visual Studio normally uses the custom msbuild build manager and that is not going to help if you try building on a *nix system.